# Does the cut operation behave differently when we try to save the curl response in a variable

Tags: linux, shell

The json response I get when I curl this specific address is

```
http://10.11.13.99:6066/v1/submissions/status/driver-20180928130922- 
0029
```

RESPONSE:

```
{ "action" : "SubmissionStatusResponse", "driverState" : "RUNNING", 
"serverSparkVersion" : "2.2.0", "submissionId" : "driver- 
20180928130922-0029", "success" : true, "workerHostPort" : 
"10.11.111.83:9000", "workerId" : "worker-20180927223442-10.11.111.83- 
9000" }
```

When I execute the below command, I get driver status as "RUNNING

```
 DRIVER_STATUS=`curl 
 http://10.11.13.99:6066/v1/submissions/status/driver-20180928130922- 
 0029 | grep driverState | cut -d '"' -f4`
```

But when I try to save the response of the curl in a variable like this

```
 RESPONSE=`curl http://10.11.13.99:6066/v1/submissions/status/driver- 
 20180928130922-0029`
```

and perform the same operation

```
 DRIVER_STATUS=`echo $RESPONSE | grep driverState | cut -d '"' -f4`
```

This gives "SubmissionStatusResponse" I am just using RESPONSE variable instead of curl. Why is this different?

Comment: my bad...by mistake

Comment: What's the different result? If you output the value of RESPONSE immediately after the curl operation what is it?

Comment: @TurtlesAllTheWayDown it gives "SubmissionStatusResponse"